# how to get x and y coordinate of image in canvas Control

Tags: windows-phone-8

Hello I am working on  window Phone 8 Application i want to get x,y coordinate of image in canvas control when image drag and drop and set image to a particular x,y coordinate

Answer (score 0):

You can use GeneralTransform to get position. If you have for example in xaml:

```
<Canvas Name="mycanvas" Grid.Row="3">
     <Image Name="myImage" Source="/Resources/Image1.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="65"/>
</Canvas>
```

Then in code you can use:

```
private Point Get_Position()
{
    GeneralTransform generalTr = mycanvas.TransformToVisual(myImage);
    Point current = generalTr.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    return current;
}
```

You can read more at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.transformtovisual.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For Drag and Drop i suggest you to use Windows Phone Toolkit GestureListener:
More description here: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-gestureservice-in-depth--key-concepts-and-api
Some Example below:

Xaml:

```
<Canvas x:Name="ImageCanvas" Margin="0,100,0,0" Background="Gray"  Canvas.ZIndex="-1" SizeChanged="Root_OnSizeChanged">
            <Canvas.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry x:Name="RectGeometry"/>
            </Canvas.Clip>
            <Image Name="image"
               Source="Your Source" 
               Stretch="None"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.ZIndex="-1">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup >
                        <MatrixTransform x:Name="previousTransform" />
                        <TransformGroup x:Name="currentTransform">
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" />
                            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" />
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener DragStarted="OnDragStarted"
                                     DragDelta="OnDragDelta"
                                     DragCompleted="OnDragCompleted"
                                     PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted"
                                     PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta"
                                     PinchCompleted="OnPinchCompleted" GestureCompleted="GestureListener_OnGestureCompleted"  />
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>    
            </Image>
            </Canvas>
```

Code Behind:

private bool _isDragging;
        private bool _isPinching;

```
 private void OnDragStarted(object sender, DragStartedGestureEventArgs args)
        {
            _isDragging = args.OriginalSource == image;
            _xChange = _yChange = 0;
        }

        private void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs args)
        {

            if (_isDragging)
            {                 

                translateTransform.X += args.HorizontalChange;
                translateTransform.Y += args.VerticalChange;



            }
        }

        private void OnDragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedGestureEventArgs args)
        {

            if (_isDragging)
            {

                _isDragging = false;

            }
            _dragCompleted = true;


        }
```